# Store and retrieve images in Postgresql using Java

Tags: java, image, postgresql, bytea

I am new to Java programming, I am searching for Java code to store images in PostgreSQL and to retrieve the image.

In PostgreSQL I have used Bytea Data-type. the image was stored. but when I retrieve I am getting NULL. I cant get the image.

Any example for this or any other suggestion on this would be helpful.

Comment: java equivalent datatype for bytea is byte. is this correct !

Comment: You need to show some code to get help!

Comment: I'd heartily recommend using Google for this kind of information seeking...

Comment: Use exactly that you say. I know perfectly it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[chapter 7](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html) of the postgresql jdbc documentation deals with storing binary data and uses an image (*.gif file) an an example. you might want to read it.

inserting an image into the db (from the link above)

```
File file = new File("myimage.gif");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, file.getName());
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int)file.length());
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
fis.close();
```

reading an image from the db (also from the link above)

```
// Get the Large Object Manager to perform operations with
LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).getLargeObjectAPI();

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT imgoid FROM imageslo WHERE imgname = ?");
ps.setString(1, "myimage.gif");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // Open the large object for reading
    int oid = rs.getInt(1);
    LargeObject obj = lobj.open(oid, LargeObjectManager.READ);

    // Read the data
    byte buf[] = new byte[obj.size()];
    obj.read(buf, 0, obj.size());
    // Do something with the data read here

    // Close the object
    obj.close();
}
rs.close();
ps.close();
```

Comment: http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/   this link too was very useful

Comment: Thanks for the link redai I was looking for this one

Answer (score -1):

Go throught the [Java Database Connectivity](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html) API and here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) of how to connect to postgres database. If any doubts.. follow up!!